# How to save a byte type char array data to a file in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a `char` type `array[100]` with `100` bytes stored in it. I want to write this `char` type byte array to a file. How could I do this?

I am not writing to a `.txt` file but some other format.

Thank you.

Comment: It'll depend on the format. If you just want to copy the array into the file in binary format, ofstream::write would be the obvious choice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No need to get complicated. Just use good old fwrite directly:

```
FILE* file = fopen( "myfile.bin", "wb" );
fwrite( array, 1, 100, file );
```

Comment: -1: This is inferior to the `ofstream`-based answers provided elsewhere in this topic. It is certainly not less complicated and it is not type safe. And it contains an error (you don't close the file).

Answer (score 30):

Some people object to using `<cstdio>`, so it is worth mentioning how one might use `<fstream>`:

```
{
  std::ofstream file("myfile.bin", std::ios::binary);
  file.write(data, 100);
}
```

The four lines above could be combined into this single line:

```
std::ofstream("myfile.bin", std::ios::binary).write(data, 100);
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the (little) information you've provided, one possibility would be to write the array to the file in binary format, such as:

```
std::ofstream out("somefile.bin", std::ios::binary);
out.write(array, sizeof(array));
```